# Retrieving a property associated with the highest value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an api that generates the following return.   What I am attempting to do is return the "job_id" associated with the highest "value".

```
"results": {
    "user": [
      {
        "calculation": "66.718*45.824",
        "job_id": "manufacturing",
        "value": 3057.3149106039559
      },
      {
        "calculation": "40.000*29.177",
        "job_id": "analysis",
        "value": 1167.0843873859146
      },
      {
        "calculation": "39.022*39.167",
        "job_id": "semiconductor",
        "value": 1528.3681864496498
      }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, once you've deserialized that into an object `obj`, you just loop through `obj.results.user`:

```
var result;
obj.results.user.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (!result || result.value < entry.value) {
        result = entry;
    }
});
```

More: [`Array#forEach`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18)

```js
var obj = {
  "results": {
    "user": [
      {
        "calculation": "66.718*45.824",
        "job_id": "manufacturing",
        "value": 3057.3149106039559
      },
      {
        "calculation": "40.000*29.177",
        "job_id": "analysis",
        "value": 1167.0843873859146
      },
      {
        "calculation": "39.022*39.167",
        "job_id": "semiconductor",
        "value": 1528.3681864496498
      }
    ]
  }
};
var result;
obj.results.user.forEach(function(entry) {
  if (!result || result.value < entry.value) {
    result = entry;
  }
});
snippet.log("result = " + JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Or if you want to get fancy:

```
var result = obj.results.user.reduce(function(r, entry) {
    return !r || r.value < entry.value ? entry : r;
}, null);
```

More: [`Array#reduce`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21)

```js
var obj = {
  "results": {
    "user": [
      {
        "calculation": "66.718*45.824",
        "job_id": "manufacturing",
        "value": 3057.3149106039559
      },
      {
        "calculation": "40.000*29.177",
        "job_id": "analysis",
        "value": 1167.0843873859146
      },
      {
        "calculation": "39.022*39.167",
        "job_id": "semiconductor",
        "value": 1528.3681864496498
      }
    ]
  }
};
var result = obj.results.user.reduce(function(r, entry) {
  return !r || r.value < entry.value ? entry : r;
}, null);
snippet.log("result = " + JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```